# Graph Database neo4j connectivity with HTML form

Tags: html, neo4j, graph-databases

how do I connect my graph database with my HTML form so that the data  from my form enters the database.I have just started using Graph Database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to query your graph via on of the offered apis as described at http://www.neo4j.org/develop/drivers (Java, PHP, ..)

Nice starting-lecture is the book offered (for free) at http://www.neo4j.org/learn